# Parsing String and Creating a jsonFormat.txt file with a json format inside

Tags: java, android, json

I want to create a json format text. Here is my string..

```
String displayContents = "|Fname:Jose Marie|Mname: Baguio|Lname: Chan|";
```

And I want this kind of output. Say jsonFormat.txt contains

```
{"Fname": "Jose Marie", "Mname": "Baguio", "Lname": "Chan"}
```

Here is my code so far.

```
String data = (String) displayContents;
    StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder();
    String delim = "|";

    String[] tokens = data.split(delim);
    File myFile = new File("/sdcard/jsonFormat.txt");
    buff.append(tokens);

    data = data.substring(1, data.length()-1);
    FileOutputStream fOuts = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

    for(int index=0;index < tokens.length ;index++){
        String[] sub_tokens = tokens[index].split(":");
        jsonObject.put(sub_tokens[0],sub_tokens[1]);
    }

    OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOuts);
    myOutWriter.append(jsonObject.toString());
    myOutWriter.close();
```

Here's the code so far.

Comment: And what was the result of your code so far?

Comment: @AlexJolig the jsonFormat.txt only contains {java.lang.String;14162b0} :(

Comment: because you append the object ( tokens ) of array rather than the content of the array

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira what do you mean sir ?

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
String[] tokens = data.split(delim);
File myFile = new File("/sdcard/jsonFormat.txt");
buff.append(tokens);
```

this will save comma separated String in text file as:

```
{,Fname:Jose Marie,Mname: Baguio,Lname: Chan,}
```

Create a valid JSON string as:

**1.** Remove `|` from start and end :

```
  data =data.substring(1, data.length()-1);
```

**2.** spilt String using `|`:

```
String[] tokens = data.split(delim);
```

**3.** Again spilt String using`:` delim and create a `JSONObject`:

```
   JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
   for(int index=0;index<tokens.length();index++){
       String[] sub_tokens = tokens[index].split(":");
       jsonObject.put(sub_tokens[0],sub_tokens[1]);
    }
```

**4.** Now save `jsonObject` in `jsonFormat.txt` :

```
OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOuts);   
myOutWriter.append(jsonObject);
myOutWriter.close();
```

Finally string stored in text file as:

```
{"Fname": "Jose Marie", "Mname": "Baguio", "Lname": "Chan"}
```

Which is valid JSON String.

Instead of using `String.spilt` we can also create `regex` for extracting data from provided String

Comment: It says in myOutWriter.append(jsonObject);  cannot resolve method 'append(org.jsonJson.Object).

Comment: @DecryptDCode: Use `myOutWriter.append(jsonObject.toString());`

Comment: Sir? what must be my String delim contain ? My delim = "|" where is the code for inserting comma(,) sir?

Comment: Sir I tried your code but my jsonFormat.txt is empty. :( nothing has been saved.

Comment: @DecryptDCode: no need to insert `,` manually because `JSONObject ` do it for us

Comment: I've added the updated code so far. Please check the code above.

Comment: @DecryptDCode: please see my answer still you are not doing in same way as i mentioned in my answer

Comment: Sir ? I've done everything but still got an empty textfile. Have you tried to run your code sir ? :)

Comment: @DecryptDCode: Dear, add debugger and check where it is breaking, also remove `buff.append(tokens);` line

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя K Ok. sir. I'll try to trace i'm new in java language :)